# How to capture and display image in custom listview

Tags: android, image, android-intent, bitmap, capture

I have a custom listview that include a textview, checkbox and imageview. If checkbox is checked, textview and imageview will be visible. When I click textView, I take a photo and display in imageview. Because I can't call onActivityResult in adapter, so I call it in Activity and I want to send position of object in listView from adapter to activity, but it send a error that position I receive in MainActivity is null. So, how can I solve this?

Here is my .xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/item_root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="2dp"
android:paddingBottom="2dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:orientation="horizontal">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_instore"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Product"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chk_instore"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:checked="false"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="5dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Capture"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:id="@+id/txtCapture"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is in adapter:

```
txtCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mContext.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
               Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
               i.putExtra("position",position);
               ((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(i, 100);
            }
        }
});
```

Here's my onActivityResult() in MainActivity:

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode==100&&resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        Bitmap b = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
        int position = (int)data.getExtras().get("position");
        POSMQty p = arrPOSMInstore.get(position); 
        p.setBitmap(b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The intent you get in on activity result is not the same one which you passed on startActivityForResult(). That's why you did not receive position.

For that you can save the position in activity and use it in onActivityResult().

Answer (score 0):

Problem is Intent you are sending to open the Camera Activity is totally different from Intent your receiving in your activity result. The intent receiving is created by Camera Activity to send the image data to your activity.

Here is one solution how you can do it.

Declare a variable in your adapter as position clicked

```
private int posClicked = -1;
```

and in your

```
txtCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mContext.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
               Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
              // i.putExtra("position",position);
              posClicked = position;
               ((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(i, 100);
            }
        }
});
```

then create a method in your adapter after activity Result

```
public void afterActivityResult(Bitmap bmp,.. extra){
  //do the need full
}
```

in your activity result

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode==100&&resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        Bitmap b = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
        int position = (int)data.getExtras().get("position");
        POSMQty p = arrPOSMInstore.get(position); 
        p.setBitmap(b);
        yourAdapter.afterActivityResult(...);
```

}
}

You can also make getter method for clickedPosition method.

in your adapter

```
public int getClickedPosition(){
     return posClicked;
}
```

and use it like

```
adapter.getClickedPosition()
```

in your activity.

Comment: so, can I get position in my activity?

Comment: Edited my answer for you. Upvote and mark right if it helps.